# collection not getting any response from instagram url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, instagram

I'm reading in json data from an instagram url in a collection, and fetching the collection data in a view, but not getting any response. What's wrong?

Model:

```
        define([
          'underscore',
          'backbone'
        ], function(_, Backbone) {var TopListModel = Backbone.Model.extend(return TopListModel;});
```

Collection:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/topList/topListModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, TopListModel){
  var TopListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: TopListModel,
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+hashtag+'/media/recentaccess_token='+access_code,
  });

 return TopListCollection;
});
```

View:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/sidebar/topList.html',
  'collections/topList/TopListCollection',
  //'text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, topList, TopListCollection){

  var TopListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#sidebar"),
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');

      var topListCollection = new TopListCollection();
      topListCollection.fetch({success: function(collection, data){            
        console.log(data);
      }});
      //this.render();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define([
      'underscore',
      'backbone'
    ], function(_, Backbone) {var TopListModel = Backbone.Model.extend(return TopListModel;});
```

Should probably be:

```
define([
      'underscore',
      'backbone'
    ], function(_, Backbone) {var TopListModel = Backbone.Model; return TopListModel;});
```

Better yet, unless you're doing something special in the model, you don't need to actually define it. Backbone will just create a model based off of the response.